# What would cause images to break ONLY when designated as a 404 page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've got a wordpress site that is showing images correctly on all other pages, except the designated 404 page. To make things more confusing, if I change the page from being the 404 page it then begins to work correctly again and whatever the new 404 page is no longer displays images.

Tried using multiple browsers, clearing the cache, uninstalling/reinstalling the 404 plugin, switching to other pages, rebuilt the page.

The 404 page: https://spacetourismguide.com/oops-youre-lost-in-space/
(Or just make up a url on that domain)

Comment: You are mixing `http` for images in an `https` page, look at the page source and console, images are founded but not in the same protocol

Answer (score 0):

on your 404 site your image link is at

http://spacetourismguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Header-Logo.png

but your image is actually located at

https://spacetourismguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Header-Logo.png

(add the s) :) you're welcome

[image: canusedevtools]

Comment: Oh weird!! Thank you!